# Make Bootstrap navbar collapse on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my Bootstrap navbar change between its non-collapsed state & mobile/collapsed state once I scroll past it on the regular desktop version.

I have tried to utilise jQuery however this forces me to write the css changes which occur to cause the collapse line by line within the jQuery once scrollTop > number of pixels.

Even when I did the above, unfortunately even though the mobile navbar would appear, the menu options would always be there and would not close upon clicking the hamburger.

I can't help but think there must surely be an easier way to do this but I'm very new to Bootstrap.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT, here is the code I have tried:

This CSS is what causes the navbar to switch to the mobile version at the advanced point I want it to:

```
@media (max-width: 1150px){
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    /* since 3.1.0 */
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }

    .navbar-static-top { 
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
        width: 100%; 
        margin: 0; 
    }
```

Here is the quick code I used to try and apply that css to the desktop header after scrolling past 50 px:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $document = $(document);

    $document.scroll(function() {
      if ($document.scrollTop() >= 50) {
        /*$('.navbar-header').css('float', 'none');
        $('.navbar-toggle').css('display', 'block');
        $('.navbar-collapse').css('border-top', '1px solid transparent');
        $('.navbar-collapse').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1)');
        $('.navbar-collapse.collapse').css('display', 'none !important');
        $('.navbar-nav').css('float', 'none !important');
        $('.navbar-nav').css('margin', '7.5px -15px');
        $('.navbar-nav>li').css('float', 'none');
        $('.navbar-nav>li>a').css('padding-top', '10px');
        $('.navbar-nav>li>a').css('padding-bottom', '10px');
        $('.navbar-text').css('float', 'none');
        $('.navbar-text').css('margin', '15px 0');
        $('.navbar-collapse.collapse.in').css('display', 'block !important');
        $('.collapsing').css('overflow', 'hidden!important');
        $('.navbar-static-top').css('position', 'fixed');
        $('.navbar-static-top').css('top', '0');
        $('.navbar-static-top').css('left', '0');
        $('.navbar-static-top').css('width', '100%');
        $('.navbar-static-top').css('margin', '0');*/
                  } else {
      }

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you've tried?

Comment: Edited in the code now.

Comment: Ok the last thing you want to do is write all that CSS in jQuery, that's not what it's for (so I won't even go in to how you can do that in fewer lines). Write the CSS such that when the navbar has another classname, i.e. `<div class="navbar navbar-collapsed" id="navbar">`, it collapses and use `$('#navbar').addClass('navbar-collapsed')` and `$('#navbar').removeClass('navbar-collapsed')`

Comment: That's what I initially tried to do. But I'm unsure on how to go about doing it correctly. I feel like I shouldn't really be stumped with this and it should be an easy solution, but I just can't crack it for some strange reason. I'll try again.

Edit: Thanks, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: If you do find yourself needing to write some CSS in jQuery, it's better to do it all in one call, e.g. `$('.navbar-static-top').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0'});` etc (but @Popnoodles is correct: don't write all that CSS in jQuery.)

Comment: Yep. I don't normally do this, but I cannot crack this issue and resorted to doing it to try and break things up.

Comment: Right. I'm getting the navbar to stick to the top of the page now after the scroll point, but still struggling on getting it to switch to the mobile version. Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

I was also working on this to get the hamburger button to show on scroll.  It looks like you're close, but you can do the following more easily.

in your main.js (within common), add a class on scroll:

```
$(".navbar").on('affixed.bs.affix', function(){
        $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-collapsed');
    });
```

remove the class when the nav gets back to the top:

```
$(".navbar").on('affixed-top.bs.affix', function(){
        $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-collapsed');
    });
```

then add your sass for that class:

```
.navbar-collapsed{
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
/* since 3.1.0 */
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
    display: block!important;
}
.collapsing {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}

.navbar-static-top { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
}
}
```